# Setting number of items listed in drop down to variable

Tags: excel, vba

Currently have a message shown when items are exporting to PDF. Wanting to get the total amount of items from drop down to represent the x value of (Exporting y of x). Currently have a fix value.

```
Const SAVE_PATH = "C:\SC\"

Sub SCtoPDF()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("G11").Validation.Formula1)

    For Each cell In inputRange
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            Application.StatusBar = "Exporting Scorecard: " & counter & " of " & "32"

            [G11] = cell.Value
            ActiveSheet.Calculate
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=SAVE_PATH & cell.Value, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What dropdown? Where?

Comment: What is the content of `G11`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no validation list rows are empty:

```
inputRange.Rows.Count
```